Unable to generate dynamic task id's
I'm trying to execute the same query for a list of BQ tables as separate tasks using BigQueryInsertJobOperator
Below is my code
column_lists = '{{ var.json.bq_alerts.tables_list }}'
custom_column_lists = column_lists.split(',')

with DAG(**dag_args)as dag:

    create_cluster = DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
        task_id="sf_create_cluster",
        cluster_name="CLUSTER_NAME",
        location=REGION,
        delete_on_error=True,
        use_if_exists=True,
        retry=Retry(maximum=10.0),
        timeout=1800,
        gcp_conn_id=CONN_ID
    )

    dynamic_tasks = []
    for table_name in custom_column_lists:       
        print(f"Table name is: {table_name}")
        task_id = f"t_{table_name}"
        load_bq = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
            task_id=task_id,
            project_id=PROJECT_ID,
            location="US",
            configuration={
                "query": {"query": f"select * from us_tables.{table_name}", "useLegacySql": False}
            },
            gcp_conn_id=CONN_ID_CLINIC
        )
        dynamic_tasks.append(load_bq)  

create_cluster >> dynamic_tasks

However, I'm getting airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The key 't_{{ var.json.bq_alerts.tables_list }}' has to be made of alphanumeric characters, dashes, dots and underscores exclusively
The tables_list has "table1,table2". Unable to understand why the task_id is unable to generate dynamically like t_table1, t_table2. Can someone please help me understand where I'm going wrong?
